# Error with adding library using Gradle (Android Studio 2.2.2)

Tags: java, android

I want to add [this](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android) library to my project.

```
compile 'com.tom_roush.pdfbox-android:1.8.9.1'
```

However, I get this error now:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.tom_roush.pdfbox-android:1.8.9.1:
```

I updated my IDE and Gradle, tried to add .jar file as library and older versions, but it did not help. Any ideas why this is happenning? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is offline mode enabled in android studio?

Comment: I tried to make it offline, but did not help

Comment: No you need not disable.. Is it available in maven central?

Comment: If you still cannot resolve the problem open a issue on the projects issue tracker or you can download and the lib as a module